# Selecting employees and updating a DataGridView

Tags: c#, design-patterns, winforms, mvp

I've been reading up on different design patterns, mainly MVP and different adaptions of this design pattern / architecture.

Now, I've decided to have a little play with my own ideas, the main outcome separating the user view, from the actual modelling which does all the data changes.

The example is simple, the user is given three radio buttons to select from

- Employee One
- Employee Two
- Employee Three

When these radio buttons are selected it changes a datagrid view with three columns

- Firstname
- Lastname
- Age

My form code has three event driven functions, `radioButton_checkChanged`.

To start with, I programatically make some new employees: (Ignore the spelling mistake!)

```
string[] employeeArray = new string[3];
employeeData emplyeeOne = new employeeData("Bob", "Smith", "21");
employeeData emplyeeTwo = new employeeData("John", "Brown", "56");
employeeData emplyeeThree = new employeeData("Andy", "Guy", "28");

 private void employeeOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateEmployee(emplyeeOne);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(employeeArray);
        }

        private void employeeTwo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateEmployee(emplyeeTwo);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(employeeArray);
        }

        private void employeeThree_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateEmployee(emplyeeThree);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(employeeArray);
        }
```

`employeeData` class (I've tried to go for encapsulation on this):

```
public class employeeData
    {
        private string classFirstName { get; set; }
        private string classLastName { get; set; }
        private string classAge { get; set; }

        public employeeData(string firstname, string lastname, string age)
        {
            classFirstName = firstname;
            classLastName = lastname;
            classAge = age;
        }

        public string[] updatePerson()
        {
            string[] data = new string[3];
            data[0] = classFirstName;
            data[1] = classLastName;
            data[2] = classAge;
            return data;
        }
    }
```

`updateEmployee` function as seen earlier:

```
 private void updateEmployee(employeeData who)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        employeeArray = who.updatePerson();            
    }
```

Am I on to the beginning of any major software design patterns here? Any adaptations and or improvements you can see to make my code a more robust?

Comment: Is this ASP or WPF?

Comment: .Net 4.5 Window Forms.

Comment: Could you please use a different title for the question. State what your code does.

Comment: I have stated what my code does, in the question haha ;)

Comment: Be that as it may, the current title applies to basically every C# question on this site. Please edit it to a short summary of what the code achieves instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

1. classes should be named using `PascalCasing` casing.
2. methods should be named using `PascalCasing` casing.
3. properties should be named using `PascalCasing` casing.

The `class` prefix does not add any value to the names. Just remove it.

**eventhandlers**

If these are really radio buttons, the checkedchanged event would be fireing for each radiobutton (if they are placed on the same control ( I assume your form )) because the nature of a radiobutton is that it is unchecked if another one is checked.

So you would need to check if the radiobutton is checked. If this is not the case no update should be done.

```
private void employeeOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;
    if (button != null && !button.Checked) { return ;}

}
```

You should then add a method which updates the view (here gridview). Right now you are doing this at 2 places. First in the eventhandler and then in the `updateEmployee()` method.

You should create a method which takes two parameters, the emploeyee to add and the datagridview where the employee should be added to.

```
private void UpdateView(DataGridView view, employeeData who)
{
    string[] employeeArray = who.updatePerson();
    view.Rows.Clear();
    view.Refresh();
    view..Rows.Add(employeeArray);
}
```

This will be called here

```
private void employeeOne_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;
    if (button != null && !button.Checked) { return ;}
    UpdateView(dataGridView1, emplyeeOne);
}
```

In this way you can get rid of the classvariable `string[] employeeArray`.

You should always declare objects as nearest where you need them as possible.

**employeeData**

The methodname `updatePerson` does not really reflect what the method do. A better name would be `GetAsStringArray[]`.

The properties are a nice to have, but as they are `private` you could replace them by local variables.

`Age` is usually a number and not a string, so you should change the datatype to `int`. As you need for the `updatePerson` method the age also, you can just call `ToString()` on it.

Comment: Literally learnt so much from your reply, thank you for that! I haven't been using C# for that long - came over from C++ - so things are a little different!

Answer (score 4):

- Naming is important, `C#` uses `Pascal casing` for classes and methods, so you should use `EmployeeData` instead of `employeeData`, and `UpdatePerson` instead of `updatePerson`
- Fields live in classes and thus you don't need to give them a `class` prefix

  ```
  private string FirstName { get; set; }
  private string LastName { get; set; }
  private string Age { get; set; }
  ```
- C# has a `type system` that you can use instead of declaring everything as a `string`

  ```
  private int Age {get;set;}
  ```
- `updatePerson` uses the `verb update`, and methods with verbs usually do/change things with `side-effects` but your method just converts the object to a `string[]`, and to be honest, I don't see any need for this method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will defiantly remember PascalCasing. A question about that the type system, does the program calculate what type is needed at runtime or compile time?

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Compile time, unless the type is dynamic  then it is determined at runtime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `class employeeData`, I suggest using `class Employee`. Class can encapsulate both data and behavior.

C# convention is to use Pascal casing for class, method and property names.

Here's another take on the code you shared. Note use of private setters, numeric age property and generic List class.

```
public class Employee
{
    string FirstName { get; private set; }
    string LastName { get; private set; }
    int Age { get; private set; }
    List<string> DisplayInfo { 
        get { return new List<string>() {FirstName, LastName, Age.ToString()}; } 
    }

    public Employee(string first, string last, int age)
    {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: I quite like the modifications you have done here, and I also really like the private setters. I most defiantly need think more about how I name things! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `EmployeeData` class could benefit from being [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). I would also rename the `updatePerson` method to `ToArray` (as that's what it does) and it also simplifies a lot:

```
public class EmployeeData
{
    private readonly string firstName;

    private readonly string lastName;

    private readonly string age;

    public EmployeeData(string firstName, string lastName, string age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public string[] ToArray()
    {
        return new[] { this.firstName, this.lastName, this.age };
    }
}
```